# python, zip:Discard extra elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I want to generate coupon numbers to a .txt, I set the number of elements as argument when I call it.

I use zip() to iterate to write to a .txt in two column. But zip always discard one element when I set a odd number.

Here is my code:

```
for i, j in zip(coupon[0::2], coupon[1::2]):
    w.writelines(j + '\t' + i + '\n')
```

How to deal with it?

Besides, If I try to make to 10 column a row, How to write it here?

```
for a, b, c, ....j in ~~:
```

This will be stupid and I cant type `\t` for 9 times.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could step through and slice off the chunks that you want to join.

The following function will either print the data by tab-separated columns or write it to a passed file:

```
import sys

def write_cols(data,n,f = sys.stdout):
    for chunk in (data[i:i+n] for i in range(0,len(data),n)):
        print('\t'.join(chunk), file = f)
```

For example, if `data = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']` then:

```
>>> write_cols(data,3)
a   b   c
d   e   f
g   h
```

and

```
>>> f = open("testfile.txt",'w')
>>> write_cols(data,3,f)
>>> f.close()
```

will send the same output to that file.

Answer (score 1):

You could use file option of print function, from builtin help:

> print(...)
> **print**(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
>
> Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
> Optional keyword arguments:
> *file*:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
> *sep*:   string inserted between values, default a space.
> *end*:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
> *flush*: whether to forcibly flush the stream.

```
print(j, i, sep='\t', end='\n', file = w)
```

Comment: Thanks man,first time to know I can use sep and end in print!